# How much gigabytes do I need to dedicate for the OS?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, swap, mint

So I think I had problems with Ubuntu in the past installations I've tried, and I had only dedicated the OS a small amount of 10 gigabytes and the swap 8. Now that OS crashed for some reason after installing the "21 Updates" In the software center, I was thinking maybe there isn't enough space for the OS to handle.

so I decided I would change distros from Ubuntu and try out a larger size. I only have around 20 gigabytes to play (approximately 18.9) with though so how much can I dedicate for a comfortable gaming experience? (I want to use it as my day to day OS as well)

I'll try out the answers and if anything goes crashing again I'll ask them here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a more or less basic Ubuntu with some main programms always needed about 20GB at least. Ofcourse depends on what you are going to install / update...

Comment: Thanks, I made up some space now. I will try them out and see if they work.

Comment: Hi just saw by accident here https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
that it actually says ubuntu 16.04. requires "25 GB of free hard drive space" depends what ubuntu you're installing

Comment: Yeah, gotcha. I installed it with 50 and 5 swap. and its going smooth as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider your swap size - the recommended is about 1.5 x RAM
so if you had 4GB of RAM I would suggest using 6GB of swap size as you have limited storage to play with.

Comment: Thanks for the intel. I moved up some of the space over to a new 1 TB drive that I just bought so I have 72 gigabytes to play with. There is one problem though, My disk manager says I have 20 gigabytes of "free space" rather than unallocated. This is normal and I can combine them regardless right?

Comment: You can try to delete the "Free Space" and then it will become unallocated. The "Free Space" is a partition that was made but never formatted.

Comment: You were correct! Thanks for the help. I have combined and created a bigger partition and swap for the Ubuntu. I'll let you know if anything goes wrong.